# Cloud Provider IP Address Resolution

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, cloud, digital-ocean

Is there a way to determine if an IP address resolved to a particular cloud provider (AWS, Azure, GCP, Digital Ocean)? Something like this:

```
# Returns 'Azure'
whichCloud('256.256.256.256')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could write a tool based on data such as:

1. Amazon - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html
2. GCP - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#find_ip_range
3. Azure - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

I'm not aware of something directly like this.  However, you can change it around a bit.  For example, my host is on Amazon.  I can do a `whois my.ip.addr.ess` and I get:

```
$ whois my.ip.is.here

#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/tou/
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/inaccuracy_reporting/
#
# Copyright 1997-2020, American Registry for Internet Numbers, Ltd.
#


NetRange:       52.0.0.0 - 52.31.255.255
CIDR:           52.0.0.0/11
NetName:        AT-88-Z
NetHandle:      NET-52-0-0-0-1
Parent:         NET52 (NET-52-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Allocation
OriginAS:       
Organization:   Amazon Technologies Inc. (AT-88-Z)
RegDate:        1991-12-19
Updated:        2015-03-20
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry//ip/52.0.0.0
```

The other environments should be similar.  It's not exactly what you want but it might get you closer.

Comment: Thanks, not as convenient as I had hoped, but this works for me!